# R Readr returns wrong values

Tags: r

I'm using the `readr` package in R to read in an `https://...[tsv.gz]` file:

```
library(readr)

x <- read_file_raw(`"https://....tsv.gz"`)
```

Instead of tab-separated output with column names and data lines, the function returns a string of characters:

```
head(x,n=10)

3c 21 44 4f 43 54 59 50 45 20
```

Any advice for how to fix my syntax? I've tried `read_file` and `read_tsv`, but both had their own issues. Thank you.

Comment: Probably because the file is gzipped, as indicated by the `.gz` suffix?

Comment: According to the docs `read_tsv` and `read_raw_file()` should handle `.gz` files. Reading to raw file will result in a `raw` vector of bytes. As you don't show the first few elements of the file you want to open, there's not much we can do. Can you edit your Q and include the file format? I suspect you'll be better off getting `read_tsv` to work or asking for help on that, that proceeding with the current approach.